# Horizontal gallary view with animation in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Please see below images.

[image]

i have tried following link to perform this animation but it will not look which i want.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

what every thing you can try this is know as cover flow view

Please Follow [link1](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)  [link2](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/17/coverflow-android-complete-implementation-source-code/)

Comment: Okey, thanks for replay. i have checked it before with this links.